# Excel VBA: How to clear all contents of multiple worksheets Using a `LCASE` Identifier

Tags: excel, if-statement, vba

Here is the vba I currently have. I am needing it to delete all data in any worksheet that starts with "Demand". The code is running but no data is being deleted. Any help is appreciated!!

```
Option Explicit
Sub ClearExcelContent()
  Dim DemandData As Worksheet
  For Each DemandData In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    If LCase(Left(DemandData.Name, 6)) = "Demand" Then
      DemandData.Rows("2:" & Rows.Count).ClearContents
    End If
  Next DemandData
  MsgBox "All Demand Data has been Deleted from Consolidation Tab"
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
> If LCase(Left(DemandData.Name, 6)) = "Demand" Then
> ```

The above statement will not match any worksheet, because the LHS is all lowercase and the RHS has an uppercase `D`. Replace `Demand` with lowercase `demand`.

```
If LCase(Left(DemandData.Name, 6)) = "demand" Then
```

Comment: Thank you! This worked. I most likely will add in Compare Text to ensure it captures everything but this fixed my problem.

Answer (score 1):

These are 3 basic functions for edition of strings:

`LCase`, `UCase`, and `WorksheetFunction.Proper`

This is what they would return:

```
Demand Is Diamand
demand is diamand
DEMAND IS DIAMAND
```

if you run them like this:

```
Public Sub TestMe()

    Dim strText As String

    strText = "demaNd is dIamand"

    Debug.Print WorksheetFunction.Proper(strText)
    Debug.Print LCase(strText)
    Debug.Print UCase(strText)

End Sub
```

In order to compare the result of the functions, you should be comparing with similar string. Probably the most sure thing is to put the same string functions on both parts of the comparison. Like this:

```
LCase(Left(DemandData.name, 6)) = LCase("demand") Then
```

---

In general, if you want to make sure that `Vit=VIT` then consider adding `Option Compare Text` on top of the module. Then this would be true:

```
Option Compare Text
Sub TestMe()
    Debug.Print "Vit" = "VIT"
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Vityata, Thank you I should have added this anyway. Thanks for the helpful response.